# I forgot to include an employment on my application form, what should I do now?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

When filling in an application form (for US grad school), I skipped the employment section before completing it, and submitted it. Since I was used to including that list of employment on my previous applications, I didn't notice that I had not listed my most recent position there!

I noticed that was missing when filling in the form for another program at the same university (because these transfer the information to the new form). The position is listed on my CV though (which is uploaded in the same section of the portal).

Right now I'm panicking and don't know how to tell them I missed something that obvious in my application. They emailed me (from the grad school) two days ago and told me my file is complete and my application is forwarded to the department. What should I do now? Should I email them? Should I just let it go and hope they find the CV sufficient and won't be picky about it? Is this something that can result in withdrawing my application or cancelling a potential offer?!

(What makes me even more worried is that I'm submitting another application to the same school, but the information is going to be different!!)

Comment: I believe I once forgot to attach some suplimentary documents before summiting. After writing an email, they reopened my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is proper, and probably essential, to update them and provide the necessary information. An additional email to point out the change might be needed, if just to avoid someone learning of your latest position and wondering why you omitted it. Making a mistake is much less serious than having people think you might have reason to conceal something. So, yes. Write that email, apologize, and give the correct information.

I would *not*, however, abandon your application. People make mistakes. Sometimes "head slapping" mistakes. Everyone does it, so nearly everyone recognizes it and will be willing to excuse it, even if it causes a bit of a chuckle.